# Link clicked signal QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebengine

We already have QWebView implementation and now we want to migrate to QWebEngineView.

Through QWebView we have registered below signal to receive notification for any link is clicked on webview or not and we are getting signal in QWebView.

`connect(m_WebView, SIGNAL(linkClicked(const QUrl &)),SLOT(urlLinkClicked(const QUrl &)));`

In "urlLinkClicked" slot, we are opening new tab and open that URL into new tab.

We are facing some issue with QWebEngineView. As there is no such signal "linkClicked" exist in QWebEngineView. So we have tried below options but still  not able to find the solution.

- In main class, we have created WebEngineView class instance and setting WebEnginePage. We are able to render the website in view class but when we click on any link then we are not getting any signal so we are not able to open that new website in new tab.

  `m_WebEngineView = new QWebEngineView(this);
     m_WebEngineView->setPage(new QWebEnginePage());`
  We have also override "acceptNavigationRequest" method to get the link clicked event in mainWebEngineView but we are not able to get the link clicked event.

Any suggestion i can try ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Override QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest in QWebEnginePage subclass:

```
bool MyWebPage::acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl &url, NavigationType type, bool isMainFrame)
{
    if (type == QWebEnginePage::NavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        qDebug() << url;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Oleh, how do you get QWebEngineView to always use the "myWebPage"?  I see you can set a page with the subclassed item, but if the link is followed to a new page, it seems like the "QWebEnginePage" class will be used for the new page according to the QWebEngineView class.

Comment: @mazecreator If I remember it right I used https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setPage to provide `MyWebPage` object. Will it be indeed new QWebEnginePage object when you click on a link? I am not sure about it.

Comment: Oleh, after a quick test, it does seem to preserve the "myWebPage" class after clicking on a link.  Little surprised but probably by design.

Answer (score 1):

**use this in inherited WebEngineView and in inherited webpage we can find hoverdUrl**

```
QWebEngineView *WebEngineView::createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type)
    {
        if(type==QWebEnginePage::WebBrowserTab)
        {
            if(!hoverdUrl.isEmpty())
                QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(hoverdUrl));

             qGlobalDbg("Open external Url requiested in chat, url : " + hoverdUrl, toKIBANA|toLOG);
        }
        //qDebug()<<"============== link Clicked "<<hoverdUrl;
        return NULL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the signal "urlChanged".

See the header "Signals" on there official documentation page.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html

If this does not help I need to know what version of the Qt framework you are using.

Best Regards
/ Rasmus

Comment: I tried "urlChanged" signal but that also doesn't help when we click on link.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.6

Comment: It would not be a pretty solution, but I think you could put "if (progress == 0) { QUrl url = m_WebEngineView.url(); }" in a slot linked to loadProgress on m_WebEngineView

Comment: I just realized there's a "urlChanged" on the QWebEnginePage object as well, maybe that works?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `urlChanged` signal that `QWebenginePage` has emits only when url of current page is changed. Previous `linkClicked` signal was also emitted when url of current page was not changed. There is a way to handle this, but you would need to have access to page source code.

This functiionality is achieved through [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html) class. You would need to create webChannel object and a special callback class, which would handle call backs from webpage in a way you like. Then you would need to set this webChanell on a page you want to and do all the connections like this:

```
MyCallBackObject* callback= new MyCallBackClass();
mWebChannel = new QWebChannel(this);
mWebChannel->registerObject(QStringLiteral("MyCallBackObject"), callback);
mWebView->page()->setWebChannel(mWebChannel); // mWebView is QWebEngineView
connect(callback, SIGNAL(urlChanged(QUrl)),
        this, SLOT(linkClickedSlot(QUrl))); // connect statement, urlChanged is defined in your callback class, linkClickedSlot is a slot where you process clicked signal
```

For more reference - please use official [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-markdowneditor-example.html) from qt or the one from [kdab](https://www.kdab.com/qt-webchannel-bridging-gap-cqml-web/) or this video from [Qt Developer Days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnvnTi6XafA) conference